# Git pull vs Git Rebase head version

Tags: git

Usually this I how I push my code for merging to master

### Method 1:

```
git pull origin master
git add -A
git commit -m 'message'
git push
```

Later found pull is not the right way to have a linear history, I was supposed to rebase and then push

What I'm doing currently

### Method 2:

```
git checkout LocalBranch
git rebase master[resolve conflicts]
git add -A
git commit -m 'message'
git push
```

### ISSUE:

When I do things using method 1 it says already upto date with master
If I go with method 2 it throws lot of conflicts and after resolving I'm unable to push the code.

### Question:

1. Why does `git pull master(5abc)` and `git rebase master(4def)` point to different head versions of master.
2. `git pull` and `git rebase` won't get to the same version of master anytime?

Comment: [pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) and [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) are two different commands that do different things. What you're looking for may be `git pull --rebase` instead. If you also want to find out why you end up with lots of conflicts, and/or your push is refused, we'd need additional info - minimal history of each branch, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be clear with the working of `git pull`. Pulling from the remote *i.e.* the location of a code(can be GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, etc.) causes git to `git fetch` and `git merge`. Well what does that mean?

It means that it first **fetches** the difference between your code and the remote's code(for example let's say there are two "extra" commits on the remote), then tries to **merge** those differences into your codebase. Now, this can go smoothly in case of those 2 commits being unrelated to the commits you made on your code(say creation of a new file(s)). But, if there is a case of a change in the same part of the code, let's say your code was:

```
int a = 4;
bool x = false;
```

But the merge wants to make it:

```
int a = 5;
bool x = false;
```

This creates a merge conflict because your code says `a` is 4 but the merge says its 5, which one should git consider? Hence you get the prompt of a `merge conflict` when pulling codes. You need to solve them manually to make things work.

`git rebase master` helps you re-apply your commits in `LocalBranch` onto the master. What this means is that it takes **your** working tree and tries to meld it with the master working tree. See [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description) for a detailed analysis of this process. Rebasing would mean that whatever commits **you** made, all of them will be applied on top of the master(or maybe even in between if you want ;) ). Please see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_msiOrYLgM) video to get a better idea. As this process is a step-by-step one, it lands you onto a different commit(the one which was to be rebased first).

`git pull`(the `merge` step in particular) will take "difference" commits and try to `merge` it into your master work tree. Only after the completion of this process you can do an `add` and a `commit` and finally `push`

Also, a tip I would like to give, use an interative rebase *i.e.* `git rebase -i` to do a rebase as it provides you an interactive interface to help you rebase.

Feel free to comment if there is any more confusion still! :)

Best

*PS:* you can do a force push in case of the `rebase` to be able to push the changes onto the remote.

Comment: Lets' suppose I have feature branch. I have done changes f1 and f2 locally and I have done rebase and pushed that.

Again if I add f3 locally and do git rebase master why do I get f1 and f2 conflicts or changes every-time I do a rebase. Is there a alternative way so that every time I rebase I push only recently changed files.

Comment: I am not exactly able to understand what you are trying to convey here, but as I said, you get a conflict when there are different changes on the same part of the code in two different commits/branches, etc.
I think you should experiment a little with this(for instance, try to make commits with unrelated changes), then maybe you can find your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The correct alternative for your Method 1 to have a linear history is:

```
git add -A
git commit -m message
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master [resolve conflicts]
git push
```

Comment: git fetch
git stash
git rebase origin/master
git add
git commit -m 'message'
git push

Isn't this the way to do