# Updating Git submodule without losing my code

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, git-submodules

I'm new to Git and now I'm in this situation:

I am a Computer Science Student and now we have one git repository (which is on GitLab) from my university and in that "main" repository we are getting every 2 weeks a new project (we just need to finish the code). The projects are submodules in the main repository. The professor is updating the main repository every 2 weeks with a new project (submodule).

With `git pull` I can update the main repository and with `git submodule update --init --recursive` I can update my submodules. If a new project is already in my main repository and I am working on it, a professor can for example update the `master` branch of that submodule again (bugfixes or similar).

What would be the best solution to update that `master` branch and submodule (if my code is almost complete) without losing my code. 
I read something that I can make a new local branch and work on it and if an update comes I can easily merge my changes and that "bugfix" on `master`. But isn't that a merge conflict? I hope you understood me.

Comment: Yes you can checkout the code in a new branch. After you finished you can merge it back to master. Yes this can result in merge conflicts, but you can use a mergetool to choose by line to accept changes

Comment: If you are using an IDE, check it's documentation for working with GIT, as Stevetro said, most of them have an integrated merge tool

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Git pal! One thing I would like to say is that it would be better to use specific terms for the repositories instead of vague terms like "main repository"(you are a newbie so you are excused for now ;)

We use the term `remote` repository for the repository upstream(*i.e.*, the GitLab link which you would see on your browser when you open the repo(short for repository) on GitLab. It originally is located on someone else's computer(probably your Professor's)). The repository on your computer is referred to as `local` repository.

Moving on to your question, the approach to keep your local code fully updated with the upstream will be to:

1. Do a `git pull`. This will bring in the latest changes from the remote and merge them into your local repo. This may result in merge conflicts, which is perfectly fine since merge conflicts occur when there is a change in the same piece of code. You may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60419171/10751129) answer to know more about merge conflicts.
2. Follow it up with a `git submodule update --init --recursive`. This will update your submodules to the point where your superproject, *i.e.*, the directory containing the whole project, expects them to be.

Also, if the superproject is only has submodules and nothing else, a `git submodule update --init --recursive` would suffice.

If you'd like to know more about git or the jargon associated with it, you can refer to [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) too!

Feel free to comment if you have any further doubts! :)

Best.